# Continuous subtraction from previous row in Bigquery

Tags: sql, mysql, google-bigquery

I need to know if there is a way I can achieve a continuous subtraction like:

Where take first value of available column and keep on subtracting a constant value (10 here) to get the required column.

| Availabl | Required |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 90 |
| 100 | 80 |
| 100 | 70 |

I have used row number as a counter to subtract the number but there is a problem as **when the Required becomes 0, counter needs to restart**. (If I used row number)

| Available | Counter | Required |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 100-(1*10) = 90 |
| 100 | 2 | 100-(2*10) =80 |

Is there a method for this continuous subtraction in bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

Consider below (BigQuery Standard SQL). Could be good start for your use case

```
select Available, Counter, Required 
from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by div(pos, 1 + cast(Available/10 as int))) as Counter,
    Available - 10 * row_number() over(partition by div(pos, 1 + cast(Available/10 as int))) as Required 
  from (
    select *, row_number() over() as pos
    from your_table
  )
)
```

if applied to sample data in your example - output is

[image]

Comment: The divide won't work as I will have some numbers randomly added to any day and the values would not be linear.
Is there a direct method to subtract the previous values in a row?